# How would you add depth of field to a 2d plot (progressively blur third dimension)?

Tags: r, lattice

Hypothetical question! I like to 'xyplot' 2D lattice graphs that vary point size and color by a third dimension, i.e. X vs. Y with a panel function that grays out / reduces size of older data points, including associated text labels. I was going after the photographic technique of sharp high contrast foreground, blurry background, to focus attention.

Is there a way to actually blur plotted objects?

I was thinking I could build the plot in layers, rasterize, add gaussian blur (function of Z), merge the layers (darken / ignore white), then plot the topmost unblurred points atop the rasterized progressively blurred background image.

Does that sound feasible? Anyone attempted anything along these lines?

Alex Ryer

Comment: Interesting question... you'll probably if you provide some sample data. Adding noise and transparency could probably have a convincing effect.

Comment: Check out the smoothScatter function, you may find something useful there: http://rfunction.com/archives/595 Otherwise I would almost suggest going with a high resolution raster background with some image manipulator

Comment: Possible alternative: make each point a 3D gaussian (of varying amplitude and/or sigma) and plot the whole field in 3D.

Comment: probably more realistic to attempt with [d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1342359)